# Laravel Best Practice for Update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have few columns on a `status` table such as `upc_status`, `is_immediate`, `total_value`, `price_ticket`, `completed_by`, `completed_auto_id`.

the client can update the status any time when the work done. There is 3 major status option we need to update based on the `status code` let me know the suggestions or recommendation to reduce the line of codes. What I have done is below.

```
      //GETTING USER INFORMATIONS
        $userName = Auth::user()->name;
        $userID = Auth::user()->id;

        if ($request->status == 0) {
            $objFetch = Order::where('id', $request->id)->update([
                'upc_status' => $request->upc_status,
                'is_immediate' => $request->is_immediate,
                'total_value' => $request->total_value,
                'price_ticket' => $request->price_ticket,
                'receiver' => $userName,
                'receiver_auto_id' => $userID,
            ]);
        }
        if ($request->status == 2) {
            $objFetch = Order::where('id', $request->id)->update([
                'upc_status' => $request->upc_status,
                'is_immediate' => $request->is_immediate,
                'total_value' => $request->total_value,
                'price_ticket' => $request->price_ticket,
                'completed_by' => $userName,
                'completed_auto_id' => $userID,
            ]);
        }
        if ($request->status == 3) {
            $objFetch = Order::where('id', $request->id)->update([
                'upc_status' => $request->upc_status,
                'is_immediate' => $request->is_immediate,
                'total_value' => $request->total_value,
                'price_ticket' => $request->price_ticket,
                'approved_by' => $userName,
                'approved_auto_by' => $userID,
            ]);
        }
        $objFetch = Order::where('id', $request->id)->update($request->all());

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Status updated', 
        ], 200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only differences are the last 2 columns you're updating, then you don't need to repeat the code... Also, the `->update()` after the if is completely redundant... Fetch the model, update the specific columns, then save, once.

```php
// Set up variables for use later
$userName = Auth::user()->name;
$userID = Auth::user()->id;

// Fetch the Record from the Database
$objFetch = Order::findOrFail($request->id);

// Set the Columns that will be updated regardless of `status`
$objFetch->upc_status = $request->input('upc_status');
$objFetch->is_immediate = $request->input('is_immediate');
$objFetch->total_value = $request->input('total_value');
$objFetch->price_ticket = $request->input('price_ticket');

// Set specific Columns based on `status`
if ($request->status == 0) {
  $objFetch->receiver = $userName;
  $objFetch->receiver_auto_id = $userID;
} elseif ($request->status == 2) {
  $objFetch->completed_by = $userID;
  $objFetch->completed_auto_id = $request->input('price_ticket');
} elseif ($request->status == 3) {
  $objFetch->approved_by = $userName;
  $objFetch->approved_auto_by = $userID;
}

// Perform a single `save()` 
$objFetch->save();

// Return your `json` response
return response()->json([
  'success' => true,
  'message' => 'Status updated', 
], 200);
```